# How should I perform prostration of forgetfulness (sujuud al-sahw) when I forget one rak'a in prayers

Tags: salat, sunnah, fiqh, prostration, sujud

I was leading the Isha prayer. I forgot the last raka and the people reminded me by saying 'Subhan Allah'. So, I got up and completed that raka and I did the taya.  When the taya was complete I did 2 sujood before Tasleem (Salam).

Is it correct?

Comment: I hope this helps. [prostration of forgetfulness](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en#hl=en-IN&q=prostration+of+forgetfulness)